# How add two coverages with different bounding-box and different resolution using geotools

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, java, geotools, resolution

I'm developing a Java application with some spatial analysis operations. One of the operations is to add two coverages. But how can I add two coverages with different bounding-box and different resolution, using GeoTools?

Any idea?
Is there any sample where I can start?

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? Coverages normally only have a single resolution (sometimes with reduced resolution subsets/overviews), so how are you planning to combine two different arbitrary resolutions?

Comment: I'm trying developing a geographic calculator and I want a result equivalent to the Raster calculator option present in QGIS. That allows sum operation of two rasters with different resolutions and bounding-boxes.